# Python imports debian packages rather than pip packages

Tags: python, pip, debian

I have two debian web servers, with a mix of debian python packages and pip python packages (for now).  I'm trying to figure out why one of them defaults to importing debian packages, while the other prefers the pip packages, when a package exists in both.

Case in point, I installed pysaml2 on both machines, which brought along the latest 
pyOpenSSL (v18).  The debian package python-openssl (v14) was already on both.  On one machine, pysaml2 runs just fine.  On the other, it errors out it winds up importing the outdated debian package, until I uninstall that package, after which everything works fine.

How can I ensure the machines always check pip first?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct pip on both machines? You always have to use the pip from the environment you want to install the packages to (sometimes pip has a soft-link to a different version, check with `which pip`)).
If this is not the case and both link to the correct pip, just uninstall the debian package by hand.

Comment: Yes, the correct pip is in use.  Uninstalling the debian package is simple enough, but I'm left with a problem where updates can break applications: installing or updating a pip package installs other pip packages in accordance with its minimum version requirements.  But it keeps importing the old debian one and breaks until someone figures out the root of the problem.

Comment: Most probably the issue is in the order of `sys.path` entries, where e.g. `/usr/lib/python` precedes `/usr/local/lib/python`. To check: `python -c "import os, sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))" `, remember to use the correct python executable. Check where a module comes from: `python -c "import something; print(something.__file__)" `. To change the order in `sys.path`, you can use the `PYTHONPATH` env var: `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python/site-packages python myprog.py` etc.